# sqlite query per row

Tags: sql, sqlite

Fairly new to sqlite (and sql).  For each row in a table, I'd like to make a query and append to another table.  My current plan is to extract all items in a vector<> and make a call to sqlite for each item in vector<>.  Can this be done through a single sqlite statement?  in c/c++.
Thank you in advance.

Edit: One idea I have is to make a trigger on a new table. For each newly added row, the trigger would then use that to make a query for that row.

Example:

```
create table Persons(Id, FirstName, LastName);
create table ParentChildren(PersonsIdParent, PersonsIdChild);
```

For each Person, create a list of all possible children (e.g. same LastName), and add to ParentChildren.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that sort of thing without leaving the database:

```
insert into table1 (column11, column12, ...)
select column21, column22, ...
from table2
where ...
```

The query that feeds into the INSERT can be as complicated as needed as long as the selected columns have the right types.

---

Now that we know what your tables look like, you just have to join Persons to itself:

```
insert into ParentChildren (PersonsIdParent, PersonsIdChild)
select p.Id, c.Id
from Persons p
join Persons c on p.LastName = c.LastName
where p.Id <> c.Id
```

You can join a table to itself as long as you use unique aliases. The `p.Id <> c.Id` condition is needed to avoid trying to make someone their own child.

Comment: This answers it partially.  I still don't know the syntax to make query per row that I've selected from, say, table2.  Thank you.

Comment: @jobobo: Maybe you could include your tables and what you're trying to select in your question.

Comment: I've updated the question above with Persons and ParentChildren example. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking just links every person to every other person of the same `Lastname` (I excluded join to one self):

```
INSERT INTO PersonsChildren
SELECT p.Id, c.id
FROM   Persons p
JOIN   Persons c USING (LastName)
WHERE  p.Id <> c.Id
ORDER  BY 1,2
```

The information could be retrieved any time with the `SELECT` query used. No immediate need for a redundant entry in PersonsChildren. Except there is more to the problem ..